# Trying to connect to sql server on ec2

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2, sql, port

I moved from my home office to an office in midtown. I can't figure out how to connect to my sql server hosted on Amazon. I'm using the exact same VmWare image just on a machine in the office. I can remote into the server so I'm sure all of the ports are open on Amazon EC2 for this IP address. I'm wondering if it's a router issue or something tied to the internet of the building blocking the sql server port. I tried turning my firewall off on both machines still no go.

Does anyone have any ideas of better solutions for connecting to sql remotely? SSH, forwarding etc?

Or any ideas how I can further test what the issue could be?

Thanks so much for any help you can offer

Comment: can you check your security group settings just to be sure? And you could use ssh tunneling of the port if you have a Linux machine on EC2; I usually have one set up as a gateway with a SOCKS proxy up pretty much 24/7 for my own ease-of-use.

Comment: Is it possible to setup the ssh with windows boxes? I'm double checking those settings. thx again

Comment: Technically, yes. you can run sshd under Cygwin and connect through that. But it's a real PITA to work with; I wouldn't. You could also use some sort of VPN.